# How do I make a widget that makes the text wrap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a container that is sized relative to the window size.  I need my text widget, which is nested in this container to fill the size of the container, which I can do except the text all stays on one line.  I want the text to wrap to that it fills the height of the container and not just its width.

This is my current code,

```
Container(
                width: width * 2.5,
                height: height,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(width / 2, 0, width / 2, 0),
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.2,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/${model?.imageName}',
                          height: centerIconHeight,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        child: Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            model?.title ?? '',
                            softWrap: true,
                            maxLines: 10,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 30,
                                color: Colors.cyan),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

And this is what it looks like when I run it. Notice the text is too small because it is only on one line and matching the containers width.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`FittedBox` tries to fit the text in no matter of its size. Just remove it and text will be wrapped.

UPDATE:

```
Container(
                width: width * 2.5,
                height: height,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(width / 2, 0, width / 2, 0),
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.2,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/${model?.imageName}',
                          height: centerIconHeight,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Text(
                            model?.title ?? '',
                            softWrap: true,
                            maxLines: 10,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 30,
                                color: Colors.cyan),
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Ya, that does make the text wrap but then the text is not relative to the size of it's parent container and depending on the screen size will either be to small or overflow  it's parent's bounds.

Comment: There is an error in your widget tree. You can not place Expanded widget inside of FittedBox, it must give an error since the Expanded must be used only within a Flex, Row, Column

Comment: Try the code above I have updated